# iOS 6 New API For Turn Based Matches - Accept and Decline

Tags: ios6, game-center

iOS 6.0 has added a couple of new instance methods to the class GKTurnBasedMatch. I am not sure how to use them:

```
acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler
declineInviteWithCompletionHandler
```

Are they supposed to be used in response to receiving a turn-based match invite? Turn-based match invites are received through the GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate protocol method: handleInviteFromGameCenter.

```
- (void) handleInviteFromGameCenter:(NSArray *)playersToInvite
```

handleInviteFromGameCenter does not provide a GKTurnBasedMatch instance to use for the purposes of accepting or declining. Consequently I do not know how to use them in response to an invite.

The only methods that provide GKTurnBasedMatch instances are:

```
+ loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler
+ findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler
```

I am not sure why I would use acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler on the results of loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler, because they are matches I am already participating in.

I am not sure why I would use either of them with findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler, because this is being called to find a match. Am I supposed to accept the match after finding it?

<- Update ->

I have found one use for declineInviteWithCompletionHandler. If a user requests to delete a match they have not taken a turn in, I call declineInviteWithCompletionHandler. This way they are not recorded as having quit the match.

*When a player has not yet taken a turn, their GKTurnBasedParticipant.lastTurnDate is null*

If a user requests to play a match (that I have displayed in a list using loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler) and if the local player has not taken a turn in the match, I am calling acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler, before I display the match to the player. I'm not sure if this is necessary, it just seemed like the right thing to do.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?I have the same issue with ios6

Comment: @Aitul, I solved the issue by using the API in the way described under <- Update ->. It seems to be working fine, my app is in the app store, and many players are using it.

Comment: I can not find the "Update" part. Could you send me the link?I am dealing with this issue for 3 weeks

Comment: It's just the bottom part of my question (up above), the two paragraphs after the the text: <- Update ->

Comment: Plz check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266089/gkmatchrequest-invitation-not-showing-in-other-device, I dont understand why I am not getting the notification in the otehr device. Could be the issu related with handleInviteFromGameCenter or GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate??